# write a function to run summarize mean on a list of column names

Tags: r

I am using the mtcars data set and am creating a summarize function that will produce the mean for the list of variables mtcars.vars. How do I pass the vector of column names through the part of that supplies the column name? How would I have the function to save the summary output as a value with the column name appended?

```
    mtcars.vars = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")
    summary_function <- function(statistic){
    for(c in mtcars.vars){
       var_mean <- mtcars %>%
       group_by(am) %>%
       summarise(mean= statistic(c), na.rm = TRUE)
    }
   }
    summary_function(mean)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you want your output to look like - do you mean something like `mtcars %>% summarize(across(mtcars.vars, mean), .by = am)`?

Comment: Yeah, no need for a loop. You can just use `mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise(across(all_of(mtcars.vars), statistic))` in the body of the function. `across()` will act across multiple columns

Comment: Worth pointing out that calling a variable the name of a commonly used function like `c` is not a good idea. R is quite good at working out what you mean and you get away with it here even though you are using `c()`, but at some point you'll likely run into unanticipated issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do this with simple approach of using apply or map function. incase you wish to use the function then please check the below code

```r
mtcars.vars = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")

summary_function <- function(statistic){
  # browser()
  var_mean <- list()
  for(c in mtcars.vars){
    c2 <- sym(c)
    var_mean1 <- mtcars %>%
      group_by(am) %>%
      summarise(mean= statistic({{c2}}), na.rm = TRUE)
    var_mean <- c(var_mean,setNames(list(var_mean1), c))
  }
  return(var_mean)
}

summary_function(mean)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
$mpg
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     am  mean na.rm
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     0  17.1 TRUE 
2     1  24.4 TRUE 

$cyl
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     am  mean na.rm
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     0  6.95 TRUE 
2     1  5.08 TRUE 

$disp
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     am  mean na.rm
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     0  290. TRUE 
2     1  144. TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `purrr::map`.
The dots argument `...` is where `na.rm` is passed.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
})

summary_function <- function(data, statistic, vars, ...){
  data %>%
    group_by(am) %>%
    summarise(mean = statistic(!!sym(vars), ...))
}

mtcars.vars = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")

mtcars.vars %>% 
  purrr::map(summary_function, data = mtcars, statistic = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am  mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  17.1
#> 2     1  24.4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am  mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  6.95
#> 2     1  5.08
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am  mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  290.
#> 2     1  144.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

And a solution with base function `mapply`.
The function called is the same as above. Note that this time the output is a named list.

```r
mapply(summary_function, vars = mtcars.vars, 
       MoreArgs = list(data = mtcars, statistic = mean, na.rm = TRUE),
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#> $mpg
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am  mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  17.1
#> 2     1  24.4
#> 
#> $cyl
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am  mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  6.95
#> 2     1  5.08
#> 
#> $disp
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am  mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  290.
#> 2     1  144.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your output should look like, but you could do:

```
sfun1 <- \(d, x, a, f) sapply(setNames(x, x), \(z) by(d[[z]], d[[a]], f))

sfun1(d=mtcars, x=c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"), a='am', f=mean)
#        mpg      cyl     disp
# 0 17.14737 6.947368 290.3789
# 1 24.39231 5.076923 143.5308
```